# Adding Values to a ComboBox using a For loop

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I'm currently making a application that is meant to emulate a real life shop, right now when a customer makes a order it gives that order a unique order number. I have the option for each customer to be able to remove and edit orders. What I want is when the customer presses the remove/edit tab they are met with a drop down combo-box full with all the order numbers that have assigned.

I first start off buy creating a list of integers that should have the same amount of ints as my other array list that gets filled with orders.

```
public int[] getOrderNumbersList() {
        int[] orderNumbersList = new int[basket.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < orderNumbersList.length; i++) {
            orderNumbersList[i] = basket.get(i).getOrderNumber();
        }

        return orderNumbersList;
    }
};
```

The problem seems to be when I'm trying to add the numbers to the combo list, I'm struggling in how to separate each index of the integer list and add them one by one to the combo,

```
JComboBox comOrderNumber = new JComboBox ();
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        int p=0 ;
        sc.getOrderNumbersList();
        entOrderNumber.addItem("" + (orderNumbersList[p]));
        p++;
}
```

How far I tried to get. Sorry if I've not been clear or that easy to understand. I'm still a beginner coder.

Comment: Whats the purpose of `p`? Isn't that what `i` is for?

Comment: @peeskillet maybe OP wants to get the 0th element on each iteration?  `p` always gets set to 0.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @fvrghl No, because OP is incrementing `p` with each iteration.

Comment: @peeskillet 1) I was joking (I don't think that's actually what the OP wants) 2) OP reinitializes `p` on each iteration with the line `int p=0 ;`

Comment: @user2882181 What is the point of having a number array and an item array? I know what the item array is for, but what is the number array for?

Comment: Sorry, I've currently got two arrays. One array is filled with the products that get added when they are created, the other array goes through the first array and runs the command OrderItem.GetOrderNumber (); and takes the ordernumber and sets it as the first index of that second array list, this process continues till all the order numbers are in the second array. The problem Im trying to solve is adding each index of my second array as a string in the combo box.

Comment: JComboBox comOrderNumber = new JComboBox ();
   for (int i = 0; i<100;) {  
    sc.getOrderNumbersList();  
    entOrderNumber.addItem("" + (sc.getOrderNumbersList(orderNumbersList[i]));
    i++; 
  } The issue is from the fact I can't Resolve orderNumbersList as variable even though I should be returning it in my sc.getOrdersNumberList () ;

Comment: @user, look at my answer. I THINK this may be what you are tyring to do

Answer (score 0):

OK, I THINK I have an idea of what you're tyring to do:
Try This

```
int[] list = getOrderNumberList();  // your method returns the array of order numbers

for (int i = 0; i< list.length ; i++) {

    entOrderNumber.addItem("" + (list[i])); 

}
```